# how to call a method from one controller to another controller in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsviewcontroller

Hello everyone, I am a beginner in Mac OS Developer. I have a problem when calling a method in a controller named Controller1.

Here is my code for Controller1:

Controller1.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Controller1 : NSViewController 

- (void)LoadViewActiveCall;

@end
```

Controller1.m

```
#import "Controller1.h"
@implementation Controller1

- (void)showCallViewController:(NSViewController*)target_viewcontroller2{
    NSLog(@"Run method showCallViewController");
    NSLog(@"Parameter targe view controller 2 : %@",target_viewcontroller2);
    if(current_controller2!=nil){
        [current_controller2.view removeFromSuperview];
        [current_controller2 removeFromParentViewController];
    }
    [self addChildViewController:target_viewcontroller2];
    target_viewcontroller2.view.frame=container_Call.frame;
    [container_Call addSubview:target_viewcontroller2.view];
    current_controller2=target_viewcontroller2;
}

- (void)LoadViewActiveCall {
    [self showCallViewController:vCall];
    NSLog(@"keluar active call berhasil");
}

@end
```

I want call **LoadViewActiveCall** method on button IBAction of Controller2

Controller2.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Controller1.h"

@interface Controller2 : NSViewController

- (IBAction)audioCall:(id)sender;

@end
```

Controller2.m

```
#import "Controller1.h"
#import "Controller2.h"

@implementation Controller2

- (IBAction)audioCall:(id)sender {
    Controller1 *co1 = [[Controller1 alloc] init];
    [co1 LoadViewActiveCall];
}

@end
```

My problem is when I press **audioCall** button, but **LoadViewActiveCall** method is not being called.

*I am sorry for my bad english*

Comment: Is the `audioCall:` method getting called? If so, what does `[[Controller1 alloc] init]` return? Have you stepped through `audioCall:` in the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: yes the audioCall: is called, [[Controller1 alloc] init] is return an object (Correct me if i am wrong).
There's nothing happen, just blank or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: What views are you putting into the controller? Also, you have a 3rd view controller called `target_viewcontroller2`. What is that? You also aren't ever installing `self` in `[-Controller1 showCallViewController:]`.

Comment: I try to load a view into container view in this case is `container_call`. `target_viewcontroller2` is a parameter refer to `vCall=[self.storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"activeAudioCallWindow"];`....

If the button to call `LoadViewActiveCall` method is in the same controller it's works, but if the button in a different controller, `LoadViewActiveCall` method isn't called.
_sorry if you are confused_

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling a function from another view controller is correct only.

Please check whether you have connected the button action correctly to the function

```
- (IBAction)audioCall:(id)sender
```

pleas echeck it and reply. It is perfectly working for singleview application for ios using UIViewcontroller

Comment: Yes, the button action connected to the function is correct.

Comment: I have checked with uiviewcontroller. The function is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Add NSNotificationCenter to call a method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioCall:) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];

-(void) audioCall:(NSNotification*)notification
{
}
```

post the notification from the second view controller as below.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:obj];
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the SecondViewController in your FirstViewController.

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
"SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
```

add the method you want to call in SecondViewController header file (SecondViewController.h)

```
@interface SecondViewController : NSViewController

- (void) LoadViewActiveCall;
```

Then call from FirstViewController

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

[vc LoadViewActiveCall];
```